@capacitor/geolocation v5: is possible to show the native dialog box to ask the user to turn on the GPS?
I'm implementing a mobile app using @capacitor and using the geolocation plugin I'd like to ask the user to turn on its GPS and I want to do that using the native dialog box like GoogleMaps and other Apps are doing.

For now I was only able to show a dialog box like the one below using the Geolocation.requestPermissions() method but only after I asked the user to manually turn on the GPS. Once the user manually turned on his GPS, that method call allow me to open the following dialog box.

Is there some SDK of @capacitor/geolocation v5 (or other plugins) that allow me to open the dialog box I need (like the one in the first picture) ? If yes, are there some examples somewhere ?
Thanks in advance
